# Convert map coordinates in pixels on an image knowing geo bounding box

Tags: coordinates, pixel, box, bounding

I am having trouble trying to draw a pixel on an image.

I know the geo bounding box values minX, minY, maxX, maxY of the image. I know the image sizes.

Example:

Bounding box:
26.078158345222278,
44.48150993466972,
26.079370252344233,
44.48398544389815

Image size --> width:155, height:299

I need to draw on the image this point:
26.07896575,
44.484298499999994

Can you please help?

Comment: Are you using google map?

Comment: No. I am receiving the coordinates from an API.

Comment: May be this will help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

Comment: I don't want to use another API. I need to find an alogorithm for this..